# How to trick feeds into re-importing nodes?

Tags: feeds

I have a content type in a feature. I am using feeds to import actual nodes from one site to another. I added new fields to the content type, and re-exported it into the features module. However, the feed ran before I updated the feature on the downstream site, and now it's not pulling the new field data. I know this will work, because it's worked before when I added new fields. However this time it's grabbed the data before it knew about the new fields.

How can I trick feeds into thinking it needs to update all the nodes? I tried setting the `changed` value on the nodes in the database to the current timestamp, but that didn't work. What criteria is feeds using to decide if the node data has changed?

Answer (score 1):

In the feeds config area, under "Processor Settings", there is an option checkbox for "Skip Hash Check", which will cause the feed to update the items regardless.